# how to create Excel sheets automatically every day?

Tags: java, excel, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, apache-poi

I want to create Excel sheets with apache poi every day, while saving the other sheets if there are already some.

```
workbook.cloneSheet(0);
workbook.setSheetName(1, DateUtils.getDate());
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(1);
```

I have a template on the first sheet, I would like to copy the template every day and then change the name of it (date of the day) then complete the template with data (which I already know how to do).

But I don't know how to automate that(new sheet every day), can you help me?

SOLUTION :

```
    final int sheetNo = 0;

    if (workbook.getNames(DateUtils.getDate()).isEmpty()) {

        for (int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
            LOG.debug("Sheet name: " + workbook.getSheetName(i));
        }
        final XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.cloneSheet(sheetNo);
        final int newSheetNo = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheet);
        workbook.setSheetName(newSheetNo,DateUtils.getDate());
       }
```

Comment: What OS for the app? You can use any cron job for it

Comment: It is an application jee on windows 10

Comment: So you can use Task Scheduler

Comment: No, i want to use java to generate the excel when pressing a button in my web interface

Comment: It's confused now, you said you want to automate the process. Now you said you want to generate it by click a button. Could you please edit your question with more information and clearer